# Ошибка при выполнении скрипта с командой execute

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Вот сам скрипт:

```
exec SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
   ( name   => 'MMK2PROD.UPDATEORDERIDATTRS_PROG' 
   ,attribute => 'PROGRAM_ACTION'
   ,value     => 'begin    
   PROCESS_BATCHKEYSUPDATEMANUAL;
   UPDATEORDERIDATTRS;
   PROCESS_ALLSLUPDATEMANUAL;

end;')
    ,number_of_arguments  => 0
    ,enabled              => FALSE
    ,comments             => NULL
   );

 exec SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE
   (name   => 'MMK2PROD.UPDATEORDERIDATTRS_PROG');
```

Запускаю три процедуры, но получаю ошибку:

```
Error at line 1
ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 7:
PLS-00306: ошибочно число или типы аргументов при обращении к 'SET_ATTRIBUTE'
ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 7:
```

Не могу понять, почему не удается изменить атрибуты.

А вот то, для чего я меняю атрибуты:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_PROGRAM
    (program_name          => 'MMK2PROD.UPDATEORDERIDATTRS_PROG');
END;
/

BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM
    (
      program_name         => 'MMK2PROD.UPDATEORDERIDATTRS_PROG'
     ,program_type         => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
     ,program_action       => 'UPDATEORDERIDATTRS'
     ,number_of_arguments  => 0
     ,enabled              => FALSE
     ,comments             => NULL
    );

  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE
    (name                  => 'MMK2PROD.UPDATEORDERIDATTRS_PROG');
END;
/
```

Все процедуры рабочие.

Comment: А в документации oracle у SET_ATTRIBUTE только 3 параметра: name, attribute, value. Никаких number_of_arguments и т.п. нет, что в принципе и логично, зачем бы они там были ...

Comment: Убрал number_of_arguments, но все равно ошибка остается

Comment: остальные то же убрали ? в смысле enabled и comments

Comment: Да,убирал все, но увы ошибка остается

Comment: (name   => 'MMK2PROD.UPDATEORDERIDATTRS_PROG'  на это место ругается,

Comment: хм. посмотрите описание пакета, какие параметры он принимает. еще пару раз внимательно посмотрите на параметры. так, на вскидку больше проблем не вижу, сравнивая с докой. Попробуйте вместо exec использовать синтаксис с begin / end. Но в любом случае PLS-00306 это общая ошибка, говорящая, что процедуру вызывают не с такими параметрами, которые перечислены в ее объявлении

Comment: Ответ действительно не помог? Что интересно, это редкий случай, когда стиль кода повлиял на ошибку. Была бы скобка написана сразу за именем процедуры, вот так `SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE(...`, то была бы ошибка синтаксиса, которая была бы понятней и легче устранена.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробовал воспроизвести и создал программу как в вопросе заменив схему `MMK2PROD` на уже имеющуюся `db3`, поправил число аргументов и передаваемое значение в `value`.
И действительно, ошибка воспроизводится:

```
exec SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE 
   (name   => 'db3.UPDATEORDERIDATTRS_PROG' 
   ,attribute => 'PROGRAM_ACTION'
   ,value     => 'My_UPDATEORDERIDATTRS'
   );
```

> BEGIN SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE; END;
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SET_ATTRIBUTE'

Что всё таки делает команда `exec` выше -- она оборачивает последуещее выражение в `begin-end;` блок, возможно добавляет нехватающий `;` и запускает полученный результат.
Но, как видно в сообщении об ошибке, это касается **только первой строки**, и как следствие, попытка выполнить процедуру вообще без аргументов. 
[Цитирую](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/EXECUTE.html#GUID-A64F29C8-B5C7-426D-82E9-A8E85763F3D6):

> If your EXECUTE command cannot fit on one line because of the PL/SQL statement, use the SQL*Plus continuation character (a hyphen).

Надо:

- или экранировать перевод строк, для SQL*Plus это знак `-` (дефис)
- или, что самое простое, написать `begin-end;` блок явно

Итак:

```sql
begin
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
   ( name   => 'db3.UPDATEORDERIDATTRS_PROG'
   ,attribute => 'PROGRAM_ACTION'
   ,value     => 'My_UPDATEORDERIDATTRS'
   );
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам, я разобрался, но вы правы, в моем случае, оказывается чтобы все заработало нужно было с начало изменить STORED_PROCEDURE на блок кода отдельным действием между begin -end.